# Avoiding carrying my main SIM card

Tags: privacy, mobile, simcard

In many countries, for example, Russia where I live, you need to show an ID to obtain a SIM card. Often this is used by law enforcement to track people. Sometimes corrupt officers sell people's location data for couple hundred bucks (imagine stalking opportunities).

I want to carry a temporary SIM card and receive calls on my main SIM card using the following scheme:

`phone at home with main SIM card <-> VPN <-> My server <-> VPN <-> phone with 2nd SIM card.`

Are there any software solutions to do this? I imagine it like a remote display app with forwarded notifications of incoming call or text.

Comment: Whether you call the SIM card in your phone *Main* or *2nd* doesn't matter. The SIM card in your phone is trackable, it has to be in order to receive calls. The only way to avoid this is to use a WiFi connection without a SIM.

Answer (score 1):

This all sounds way too complicated and prone to failure.

Here's a better option: buy a virtual SIP number, install VPN on your smartphone and install any Android SIP client. You're good to go without being tracked.

If you're concerned about your privacy, ask someone you know to buy a SIM card for you. If they trust you, they'll do it.